# Mercurial - Set a Repository Root?

Tags: linux, ssh, mercurial

I am setting up a Mercurial repository layout, and have  a directory with all the repositories in it.

```
/var/vcroot/link/[repository]
```

As SSH is the only way I know of to access Mercurial remotely, I know howto setup public key authentication, and setup the appropriate environment variables. What I want to know is there any way to set the repository root so users can just type

```
ssh://connection-name/repository-name
```

As opposed to having to do this:

```
ssh://connection-name/var/vcroot/link/repository-name
```

I want something like svn's -r option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on whether users are logging in as themselves, or as a dedicated Mercurial user.  If you create a dedicated Mercurial user, and authenticate by key, then you can set the home directory of the Mercurial user to be `/var/vcroot/link`, and the single slash after `connection-name` will be relative to that.

Note that your second example will be nonfunctional due to a missing slash for that same reason (i.e. it should be `ssh://connection-name//var/vcroot/link/repository-name`).

If you have users logging in as themselves, then each user will have to create a symlink into `$HOME` for that to work.  Alternately, you can make `/hg` a symlink to `/var/vcroot/link`, and use `ssh://connection-name//hg/repository-name`, which is probably short enough to be convenient.

Comment: Don't needlessly double slashes, please.  No need for the double slash before "hg" there.

Comment: Jae is incorrect.  The double-slashes in "//hg" are absolutely required (at least as of Mercurial 1.6.4, just tested) to match my example, as a single slash will start the pathing at your home directory, not the filesystem root.

Comment: I sit corrected (I can't remember what fuzz I had on my brain at the time, because it's obvious how wrong my comment was, and I wonder why I didn't see it)

Answer (score 1):

Responding to this part of your question:

> As SSH is the only way I know of to access Mercurial remotely

You can also access mercurial remotely over http/https.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by creating a shell script /usr/local/bin/hg:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /var/vcroot/link
/usr/bin/hg $*
```

If you then remotely run 'hg init ssh://connection-name/repository-name', the repository is created in /var/vcroot/link/repository-name, and cloning and pushing work as expected. I haven't tested anything else though.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of changing the home directory to `/var/vcroot/link`, but if they log in with different user names, then that wont work.

You can instead suggest to your users that they setup a special scheme for your server. The standard [schemes extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/SchemesExtension) lets you do that. They should add

```
[extensions]
schemes =

[schemes]
server = ssh://connection-name//var/vcroot/link/
```

to a config file and then they can do

```
$ hg clone server://repository-name
```

instead of

```
$ hg clone ssh://connection-name//var/vcroot/link/repository-name
```

If you have control over their machines, then you can even enable and configure the extension in the `/etc/mercurial/hgrc` file to make it a system-wide setting.